# NGINX: How can I extract some value from URI and use it within auth_basic_user_file?

Tags: nginx, http-authentication

I'm providing several download folders for different customers. Each folder must be password protected with its own .htaccess file.

To simple up my nginx configuration, I have the following question:

How can I extract the customer name ("customerA") from URI and use it within the auth_basic_user_file?

This is the configuration I'm using right now:

```
server {
    root /usr/share/nginx/www;

    server_name localhost;

    autoindex on;

    location /build/customerA {
            index build.json;
            auth_basic "CustomerA Access Only!";
            auth_basic_user_file /usr/share/nginx/www/build/customerA/.htpasswd;
    }

    location /build/customerB {
            index build.json;
            auth_basic "CustomerB Access Only!";
            auth_basic_user_file /usr/share/nginx/www/build/customerB/.htpasswd;
    }
}
```

Thanks,
Sebastian

Answer (score 2):

If no `auth_basic_user_file` is found, nginx fails over to 403 (tested in version 1.7.5). So you could try the following regex location. The drawback is you then need to be concerned with its location in the config with respect to other regex locations, since only the first one is matched:

```
location ~ ^/build/(?<customer>[^/]+) {
    index build.json;
    auth_basic "$customer Access Only!";
    auth_basic_user_file /usr/share/nginx/www/build/$customer/.htpasswd;
}
```

To avoid this, consider wrapping the regex location with a prefix location. Then it can appear anywhere in your config and it will scale more gracefully:

```
location /build/ {
    location ~ ^/build/(?<customer>[^/]+) {
        index build.json;
        auth_basic "$customer Access Only!";
        auth_basic_user_file /usr/share/nginx/www/build/$customer/.htpasswd;
    }
}
```

Or put the regex in a map directive outside of your server stanza:

```
map $uri $no_customer {
    default 1;
    ~^/build/(?<customer>[^/]+) 0;
}
```

Then use the following prefix location:

```
location /build/ {
    if ($no_customer) { # optionally forbid if no customer specified
        return 403;
    }
    index build.json;
    auth_basic "$customer Access Only!";
    auth_basic_user_file /usr/share/nginx/www/build/$customer/.htpasswd;
}
```